# How to read the code behind standard JavaScript methods?

Tags: javascript, encapsulation

I have been Googling this, but I can't seem to find a way I can read the code behind standard JavaScript methods such as `Object.prototype.toString()` or `Document.getElementsByTagName()`. If no such method exists, is there any way to unwrap the internal complexity of a JavaScript object after it has been encapsulated?

Comment: asking for off site resources is offtopic..... but you might be able to salvage this question by just asking how to see the implementation of toString.

Comment: How the methods are implemented is up to the browser vendor, but V8 and SpiderMonkey should be available if you do a search.

Comment: @adeneo, so each browser vendor writes their own JavaScript code and that code's encapsulation has to accommodate the interface that the ECMAScript standard specifies?

Comment: @BriennaHerold—yes. ECMA-262 specifies behaviour, it does not specify implementation. See [*ECMAScript 2015 §2 Conformance*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-conformance).

Comment: Indeed, the browser vendors write their own engines, implementing the methods (mostly) according to the ECMA standard, in the language of their choosing. [**V8**](https://github.com/v8/v8) and [**SpiderMonkey**](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev) are at least openly available, but figuring out exactly what's happening, and where, isn't always easy. Good luck !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For custom functions, you can actually call the toString() method to see the code. For example, on a page that has jQuery:

```
>> $.toString()
"function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}"
```

But when you call:

```
>> toString.toString()
```

You get:

```
"function toString() {
  [native code]
}"
```

The native code is not written in JS, I'm guessing it's C++. You can see the source in the corresponding JS interpreter project, e.g. [V8](https://github.com/v8/v8/search?l=cpp&q=toString).